# What is the functionality of UniswapV2ERC20 contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap

This is [UniswapV2ERC20.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2ERC20.sol)

Uniswap created its own version, slightly different from ERC20. As far as I know ERC20 implementation is for creating Ethereum tokens. Uniswap is just swapping exchange. What does it need this "UniswapV2ERC20" implementation for? It even has its own symbol and name:

```
string public constant name = 'Uniswap V2';
string public constant symbol = 'UNI-V2';
```

That makes me think we are actually creating a new token but why

Answer (score 0):

It's used to create a pair token for a new liquidity pool here is the docs for reference!

https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/Pair-ERC-20